# How to do input for detectron2 builtinmodel?

Tags: python, image-processing, mask, detectron

I trained a model, now I would like to use it to detect objects in images. Using the DefaultDetector only the boundyboxes are returned, I would need the masks. I saw that you can also perform inference with this method:

```
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(inputs)
```

I think that's what he should use. The problem is that I don't know how to set the inputs, starting with images.

```
import torch
import glob
cfg = get_cfg()

cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/"
                                              "mask_rcnn_R_101_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "model_final.pth")
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 1
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 1 # only has one class
cfg.INPUT.FORMAT = "BGR"
#Just run these lines if you have the trained model im memory
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7 # set the testing threshold for this model
#build model
model = build_model(cfg)

DetectionCheckpointer(model).load("output/model_final.pth")

model.eval()#make sure its in eval mode

image = cv2.imread("/kaggle/working/detectron2/images/73-ab1.jpg")
height, width = image.shape[:2]
image = torch.as_tensor(image.astype("float32").transpose(2, 0, 1))
image = ImageList.from_tensors([image])

with torch.no_grad():
    inputs = image
    outputs = model(inputs)
```

Unfortunately, however, I think I'm wrong, can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Model Input Format](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/models.html#model-input-format) for the builtin models.

Basically, the model in your code is not expecting an `ImageList` object, but a `list` of `dict`s where each `dict` needs to provide specific information about one image, as explained in the documentation linked above.

So, your inference code needs to be corrected to the following.

```
image = cv2.imread("/kaggle/working/detectron2/images/73-ab1.jpg")
height, width = image.shape[:2]
image = torch.as_tensor(image.astype("float32").transpose(2, 0, 1))
inputs = [{"image": image, "height": height, "width": width}]

with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(inputs)
```

You can also see this in the code - [the `forward` method of the `GeneralizedRCNN` class](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/2409af0bf0d4bdcc685feb6d2c7fd659828acac4/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py#L122).

Comment: Yep, in the end i used the default Predictor, but i tried this also and works, thanks man. I'm new to this world.